# How to detect a declared variable that is never used?

Tags: python

In Python, I think a common potential error is to misspell a variable name on assignment, then when you wish to use the correctly spelled version of the variable, you don't get the behavior you anticipated.  For example:

```
my_variable = "Hello"
my_varible = "World"
print (my_variable)
```

The intent was to assign a new value to `my_variable`, but because there was a typo, the program prints "Hello" when the intent was "World".  I have tried ``pylint`,`pychecker`, and`pyflakes`, but either I'm using the tools incorrectly, or they don't provide a warning for this scenario.

So the question is, does a publicly available tool exist that will detect unused variables that have been assigned once and return a warning?  The ideal tool would tell me that I declared my_varible at line 2 and never used it later.

Comment: Just be perfect and never make a typo

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611776/what-are-the-comprehensive-lint-checkers-for-python).

Comment: Some IDE  like PyCharm can highlight unused variables

Comment: I think IDEs like PyCharm have built-in linters mark assigned but never used local variables for this specific reason; other python linters might do that as well

Comment: [`flake8`](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/) will warn on this.

Comment: I found quite a lot of material when I googled "Python find unused variables"

Comment: @steven maybe check out this repo https://github.com/jendrikseipp/vulture, i tested it and it seems to do as you describe. on your example it returns `script.py:2: unused variable 'my_varible' (60% confidence)`

Comment: davedwards, please post as an answer and I'll mark your answer as my preferred answer.  vulture is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Can somebody shed light as to why my question was downvoted?  It's a well-defined question and in comments above, I have received the perfect answer for my usage pattern, which is to use vulture, a nice command-line tool.  I really appreciate the quick answers (I had spent at least an hour trying other tools) and I'm happy to have asked my question, despite the confusing downvotes!

Answer (score 1):

As posted by davedwards in comments, the solution to my question was to use vulture.  On Ubuntu, I ran `pip install vulture`, then just ran vulture against my test code and received this:

vulture misspelled.py

misspelled.py:2: unused variable 'my_varible' (60% confidence)

vulture is perfect for me because if a script has no errors, it produces no output.  Since it is a command-line tool, I can automate use of this tool over a large code base.

dave, if you return to this question and post the same answer, I will delete this answer and mark yours as the preferred answer.

Comment: Hey @Steven, Vulture dev here. I see, that you mention that since Vulture is a command line tool, automation is easy. Do you know that Vulture has a Python API - called [scavenge](https://github.com/jendrikseipp/vulture/blob/665c8c7687f6e226abc49594aacf26e09ce1f064/vulture/core.py#L205) which simplifies automation greatly. (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59564370/6426752)

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm IDE shows warnings for typos and unused variables.