# Running vulture from a python script

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to find a way to run vulture (which finds unused code in python projects) inside a python script.
vulture documentation can be found here: 
https://pypi.org/project/vulture/

Does anyone know how to do it?

The only way I know to use vulture is by shell commands.
I tried to tun the shell commands from the script, using module subprocess, something like this:

```
process = subprocess.run(['vulture', '.'], check=True, 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,universal_newlines=True)
```

which I though would have the same effect as running the shell command "vulture ."

but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: So if you run vulture from cmd what it shows/what is your expectation?

Comment: a description of all the unused code I have in the folder. From the python script I get an error

Answer (score 2):

Vulture dev here.

The Vulture package exposes an API, called [`scavenge`](https://github.com/jendrikseipp/vulture/blob/665c8c7687f6e226abc49594aacf26e09ce1f064/vulture/core.py#L205-L246) - which it uses internally for running the analysis after parsing command line arguments (here in [vulture.main](https://github.com/jendrikseipp/vulture/blob/665c8c7687f6e226abc49594aacf26e09ce1f064/vulture/core.py#L578-L584)).

It takes in a list of Python files/directories. For each directory, Vulture analyzes all contained *.py files.

To analyze the current directory:

```
import vulture
v = vulture.Vulture()
v.scavenge(['.'])
```

If you just want to print the results to stdout, you can call:

```
v.report()
```

However, it's also possible to perform custom analysis/filters over Vulture's results. The method [`vulture.get_unused_code`](https://github.com/jendrikseipp/vulture/blob/665c8c7687f6e226abc49594aacf26e09ce1f064/vulture/core.py#L248-L270) returns a list of [`vulture.Item`](https://github.com/jendrikseipp/vulture/blob/master/vulture/core.py#L97) objects - which hold the name, type and location of unused code.

For the sake of this answer, I'm just gonna print the name of all unused objects:

```
for item in v.get_unused_code():
     print(item.name)
```

For more info, see - https://github.com/jendrikseipp/vulture

Answer (score 0):

I see you want to capture the output shown at console:

Below code might help:

```
import tempfile
import subprocess

def run_command(args):
    with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as t:
        try:
            out = subprocess.check_output(args,shell=True, stderr=t)
            t.seek(0)
            console_output = '--- Provided Command: --- ' + '\n' + args + '\n' + t.read() + out + '\n'
            return_code = 0
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            t.seek(0)
            console_output = '--- Provided Command: --- ' + '\n' + args + '\n' + t.read() + e.output + '\n'
            return_code = e.returncode
        return return_code, console_output
```

Your expected output will be displayed in `console_output`

***Link:***

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: thanks! I tried to run it (return_code, console_output = run_command(['vulture', '.'])) but still get an error..

Comment: Can you provide the displayed error? bdw try to pass it as string instead of list. Something like ``"vulture . "`` I'm not sure whether it accepts list